# Firebase dynamic link default behavior if link not registered

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there a way to set a default behavior for dynamic links that are not "registered"

I may allow users to share the app. It would be nice to have https://myapp.page.link/user_id_1234

Where I have not registered user_id_1234 with the Firebase Dynamic Link console. I know I can programically create these links but i'd rather just have a "default" behavior that happens when the link is not registered.

Is this possible?

Optionally it would be nice to have https://myapp.page.link/default?user_id=1234

But this does not seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing deep links with dynamic links. Dynamic links handle your deep links to content depending upon the platform.

Example you have a deep link: https://example.com/user/1234

Suppose you created a domain for dynamic link from console: https://myapp.page.link

Now you can create a dynamic link which opens the deep linked content on your app. The dynamic link can take in only specific parameters as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually#parameters). However you can pass your parameters to your deep link,

https://myapp.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fuser%2F1234&apn=com.example.app&ibi=com.example.app

The above dynamic link opens the deep link in your android app with package name  `com.example.app` and ios app with bundle ID `com.example.app`.